# Posting data to action method MVC2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have 2 action methods inside the controller.

```
public ActionResult SelectOrders()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult ProcessOrders(String OrderNos)
{
return View();
}
```

On SelectOrders View, user will select the order IDs and when he clicks on Submit, Selected order numbers are getting displayed on ProcessOrders View. Currently I am storing the selected acc numbers in a Javascript Array and passing through Query String to ProcessOrders view (Window.href). I am sure this is not the best way to do this job as there could be more than 100-200 orders that user can select. What is the other possible/best way to handle this functionality.

Comment: Are the orders dynamic or always the same?

Comment: Orders will be loaded only once with the page.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is model.
this would be mine solution.

define entity for order

```
public class OrderItem{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

collection of orders to pub into select orders

```
public class SelectOrdersModel{
public IEnumerable<OrderItem> Orders{get;set;}
}
```

Now modify your controller:

```
public ActionResult SelectOrders(SelectOrdersModel model)
{
 SelectOrdersModel modelToDisplay = (model==null)? new SelectOrdersModel():model;
 //populate model here
 return View(modelToDisplay);
}
```

and to get data:

```
public ActionResult ProcessOrders(SelectOrdersModel model)
{
// process your model here
```

if (!ModelState.IsValid) return RedirectToAction("SelectOrders", model);
//     redirect or do your logic here
    }

Redirection in form you will do as:

```
<% using( Html.BeginForm("ActionName"))
   {
       //your form data here
   }%>
```

Comment: Thanks cpoDesign. But there are 2 questions here. 1) My understanding is, when you select orders and submit the form(SelectOrders), it will get submitted to SelectOrders action method and not the the ProcessOrders Action method. Hw can we submit from 1st Action method to 2nd 2) How can we store the selected orders in model on View? These orders are renderd with a checkbox associated with it in a table.